# Reading an xml file and mapping to text boxes

Tags: xml, vb.net

I am running into troubles while loading an XML and reading its contents. I am getting a blank result and unable to fill the values to text boxes.
My XML looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Layout Type="Create">
  <Function_String>FunctionString</Function_String>
  <CaseString_Col>m</CaseString_Col>
  <ID_String>AccountID</ID_String>
  <Topic_Col>n</Topic_Col>
  <Sub_Topic>o</Sub_Topic>
  <ID_Col>e</ID_Col>
  <Notes>test</Notes>
</Layout>
```

I need values in Function_string,CaseString_col.... i.e. FunctionString,m,... to be mapped to specified text boxes.

Please suggest

Comment: "I am running into troubles" what specific troubles? What does your code look like? As it stands, this question is not valid.

Comment: trouble is reading this xml file. please suggest

Comment: Of course! I suggest you copy your efforts thus far, and edit your question, pasting your code. That way the SO community can identify any specific issues with your code. I assume you already know that SO is not a code request forum, and we generally expect that you have tried something thus far. If you didn't know that, then please visit http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

Try xml linq

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq
Module Module1
    Const FILENAME As String = "c:\temp\test.xml"
    Sub Main()
        Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(FILENAME)
        Dim function_String As String = CType(doc.Descendants("Function_String").FirstOrDefault(), String)
        Dim caseString_Col As String = CType(doc.Descendants("CaseString_Col").FirstOrDefault(), String)
        Dim iD_String As String = CType(doc.Descendants("ID_String").FirstOrDefault(), String)
        Dim topic_Col As String = CType(doc.Descendants("Topic_Col").FirstOrDefault(), String)
        Dim sub_Topic As String = CType(doc.Descendants("Sub_Topic").FirstOrDefault(), String)
        Dim iD_Col As String = CType(doc.Descendants("ID_Col").FirstOrDefault(), String)
        Dim notes As String = CType(doc.Descendants("Notes").FirstOrDefault(), String)

    End Sub

End Module
```